consequences of claims or lack thereof on foreign countries
I've heard that in some foreign countries, if you file based on a provisional application that do not have claims, then those countries will restrict you to only the embodiments of the specifications.
Can someone elaborate on that?

It is a persistent rumor. It is not true for any major country. If it does apply to some obscure country I have never heard it named so it could be verified or disproven.
If there is such a place, you are not applying there.
There are many ways to screw up a patent filing, you can worry about those.
